# Powershell Filter ADgroups the right way

Tags: powershell

Hi im trying to Filter AD-Groups by a string i defined in a variable:

```
$groupname="string"
Get-ADGroup -filter {GroupCategory -eq "security" -and Name -like ($sgroup_name+"*")}
```

How do i do this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String expansion doesn't work well with the `-Filter` parameter when passing it a script block - use a string filter instead:

```
$groupname = "string"

Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'security' -and Name -like '${groupname}*'"
```

Comment: I know you just copied what the op had but the code should work as intended now.